# What is the difference between an application that depends on X server and one on Wayland?

Tags: linux, user-interface, xorg, xserver, wayland

How do I recognize if an application depends on X server ?
How do I build an application that does not depend on X ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what library you use to create your graphical interface (or capture the mouse and keyboard event).

- If your application directly links to xlib, then it's X dependent for sure (obviously).
- Gtk, Qt, SDL and many others now support the wayland protocol and can be configured to go for it quite easily without any modification to the application.
- Now, if your code uses directly libwayland or one of its bindings (or rewrites), it is only Wayland (as obviously as for xlib).

To sum up, the best way to avoid graphical server dependence is to leave it to a third party library that already solved the struggle.